# If $f$ is bounded and if $f^2$ is Riemann integrable, then is f Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

This was on a past exam paper, and it was asking if $f$ is bounded and if $f^2$ is Riemann integrable, then is f Riemann integrable?

If I had to guess, I'd say no. I tried creating an $\epsilon$ argument, but I feel like I'm grasping at straws, so I'd appreciate a hint towards a slightly more concrete proof.

Comment: $\frac 1x$ fails to be Riemann integrable over $[1,\infty)$ in the sense that its integral is not finite, but I'm not sure if that's the kind of answer being sought.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom (proper) Riemann integration is only defined for compact intervals so $1/x$ is not an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $f \colon [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \\
-1 & x \in [0,1] \setminus (\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]). \end{cases}. $$

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider
$$ f(x) = 2\chi_{\mathbb{Q}} - 1
$$
where $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the indicator of the rational. $(f)^2 = 1$, which is Riemann integrable, but $f$ is not Riemann integrable by Lebesgue's criterion of Riemann integrability.